# Where 2-D DFT is necessary in image processing applications instead of 2-D DCT?

Tags: fft, dft, image-processing, dct

As we know the 2-D DCT is a real-valued kernel and less computational complexity and it used in several image processing applications like image compression etc. 2-D DFT is a complex kernel and high computational complexity, So in which image processing application of 2-D DFT is more advantageous than 2-D DCT?

Why DFT is instead of DCT in image processing applications?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Sukumar.

Answer (score 1):

Any place you would like to filter an image with anti symmetric filter.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.                                                                                                                      If you have come across any particular image processing application, could you please mention it here?

Comment: If you happen to design a filter which isn't symmetric (Derivative Filter for instance) you can't filter it in DCT.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.  If anyone knows about any other application, please post it here.